# List of all possible values of a function

Tags: haskell, reflection, functional-programming

I have multiple objects each associated with a String. Is there some pattern that allows a type safe way to get the list of all Strings?

```hs
data MyObject = Foo | Bar 

getObjectString :: MyObject -> String
getObjectString Foo = "Foo"
getObjectString Bar = "Bar"

-- Bad because not type safe and String duplication
listOfAllObjectStrings :: [String]
listOfAllObjectStrings = ["Foo", "Bar"]
```

Different solution that is still not type safe but reduces String duplication.

```hs
data MyObject = Foo | Bar 

getObjectString :: MyObject -> String
getObjectString Foo = listOfAllObjectString !! 0
getObjectString Bar = listOfAllObjectString !! 1

listOfAllObjectStrings :: [String]
listOfAllObjectStrings = ["Foo", "Bar"]
```

Comment: I've added the _reflection_ tag. I hope I've done right.

Comment: A [`Representable` functor *f*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html) is isomorphic to a partially applied function type `(Rep f ->)`, I don't recommend it for your problem but you can apply `tabulate :: (MyObject -> String) -> F String` to `getObjectString`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all values of `MyObject` once you've made it derive `Enum` and `Bounded`. Then, you'll apply `getObjectString` to each value to get a string value.

```
data MyObject = Foo | Bar deriving (Enum, Bounded)

getObjectString :: MyObject -> String
getObjectString Foo = "Foo"
getObjectString Bar = "Bar"

listOfAllObjectStrings :: [String]
listOfAllObjectStrings = map getObjectString [minBound .. maxBound]
```

Comment: Alternatively, [`getObjectString<$>universe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.2.1/docs/Data-Universe.html#v:universe).

Comment: `universeF` would probably be more appropriate as long as you are going to add an extra dependency.